# Is any real program checks for file close errors?

Tags: io, filesystems, operating-system

I have never seen a real use for checking if a file was closed correctly. I mean, if it didn't close, then what? You have nothing smart to do. Beside, I'm not sure if there's a real world use case, where non of the `write`/`reads`/`flush` will fail, and only the `close` will.

Does anyone actually uses the return value of `close`?

Comment: Windows kernel doesn't ever expect the filesystem to fail on Close operation. I.e. file system driver must unconditionally complete the operation. Don't know about other OS though.

Answer (score 2):

From the close(2):

```
Not checking the return value of close() is a common but nevertheless serious
programming error. It is quite possible that errors on a previous write(2)
operation are first reported at the final close(). Not checking the return
value when closing the file may lead to silent loss of data. This can
especially be observed with NFS and with disk quota.
```

And if you use signals in your application `close` may be interrupted (EINTR).

EDIT: That said, I seldom bother unless I'm prepared to handle such cases and write code that has to be 100% fool-proof.

Comment: Not exactly what I asked. Are there real programs that actually check it? The man page didn't convince me. If you want to make sure the data hit the disk, `flush` is your friend, not `close`, that accidentally flushes.